# why call is not working in wso2 esb

Tags: wso2, call, esb, mediator

I have a problem with wso2 esb.
I wrote a proxy and in that I call an endpoint to do some changes on original input. but the log before call and after call is the same(it should be different). It seems the call is not working at all.when I send respone to outsequence it is null. Can any one say why this happen? (I have tested my endpoint in soupUI)

this is my proxy:

```
      <inSequence>
     <property name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName" value="GET" scope="transport"/>
     <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
     <smooks config-key="smooks-csv1">
        <input type="text"/>
        <output type="xml"/>
     </smooks>
     <iterate continueParent="true"
              preservePayload="true"
              attachPath="//csv-set"
              expression="//csv-set/search"
              sequential="true">
        <target>
           <sequence>
              <xslt key="gov:/first.xsl"/>
              <xslt key="gov:/second.xsl"/>
              **<log level="full"/>
              <call blocking="true">
                 <endpoint>
                    <address uri="MyEndPiont"/>
                 </endpoint>
              </call>
              <log level="full"/>**
           </sequence>
        </target>
     </iterate>
     <respond/>
  </inSequence>
  <outSequence>
     <aggregate>
        <completeCondition>
           <messageCount min="0" max="100"/>
        </completeCondition>
        <onComplete expression="//Guest">
        </onComplete>
     </aggregate>
  </outSequence>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. List of changes:

- Removed `respond` mediator.
- Replaced `call` by `send`.
- Added `send` in out sequence.

  ```
    <inSequence>
       <property name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName" value="GET" scope="transport"/>
       <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
       <smooks config-key="smooks-csv1">
          <input type="text"/>
          <output type="xml"/>
       </smooks>
       <iterate continueParent="true"
                preservePayload="true"
                attachPath="//csv-set"
                expression="//csv-set/search"
                sequential="true">
          <target>
             <sequence>
                <xslt key="gov:/first.xsl"/>
                <xslt key="gov:/second.xsl"/>
                <log level="full"/>
                <send>
                   <endpoint>
                      <address uri="MyEndPiont"/>
                   </endpoint>
                </send>
             </sequence>
          </target>
       </iterate>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence>
       <aggregate>
          <completeCondition>
             <messageCount min="0" max="100"/>
          </completeCondition>
          <onComplete expression="//Guest">
          </onComplete>
       </aggregate>
       <send />
    </outSequence>
  ```

Comment: unfortunately with these changes again I can not see the output in outsequence. it gives me this error: "ERROR - VFSTransportSender Error while attaching VFS file system properties. null
ERROR - VFSTransportSender Unable to determine out transport information to send message". what should I do? thanks in advance

Comment: Can you try removing `OUT_ONLY` property?

Comment: with removing this I can see the result. But it gives me an error because I use VFS and this is async. in the send part I am writing the response into a file. This is error: "The VFS transport doesn't support synchronous responses. Please use the appropriate (out only) message exchange pattern"

Comment: what do you mean by the `send` part?

Comment: in outsequence I should send the result to a file. this my code after aggregate: "<send><endpoint name="FileEpr"><address format="soap11" uri="vfs:file:///C:/Users/output.txt"/></endpoint></send>"

Comment: That statement is about the VFS sender. In your insequence you only read files (i.e. you use VFS Listerner). So you shouldn't have `out_only` there. if you want to write the response to a file, you can do that inside aggregate mediator. Maybe it'll work if you put `out_only` before aggreate mediator, inside outsequence.

Comment: Thanks very much. with your help I solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try `blocking="false"`. Please note that making this change does not make the call mediator is asynchonus. It's synchronous regardless of whether blocking is true or false. Blocking is just an implementation detail.

> The Call mediator is used to send messages out of the ESB to an
>   endpoint. You can invoke services either in blocking or non-blocking
>   manner.
>
> When you invoke a service in non-blocking mode, the underlying worker
>   thread returns without waiting for the response. In blocking mode, the
>   underlying worker thread gets blocked and waits for the response after
>   sending the request to the endpoint. Call mediator in blocking mode is
>   very much similar to the Callout mediator.
>
> In both blocking and non-blocking modes, Call mediator behaves in a
>   synchronous manner. Hence, mediation pauses after the service
>   invocation and resumes from the next mediator in the sequence when the
>   response is received. Call mediator allows you to create your
>   configuration independent from the underlying architecture.

Quoted from https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Call+Mediator

Comment: enable wire logs and see. http://lakshanigamage.blogspot.com/2015/03/how-to-enable-wire-logs-in-wso2-esbapim.html

Comment: @ Bhathiya thank you very much. Now I can see the the desired output in console. but why in normal condition I could not see the result? How can I save this result?

Comment: when I enable wire log I can see the correct output. Can you tell me why this happens? How can I save the result? and why respond does not send anything to out sequence?

Comment: Enabling wire log doesn't have any connection to functionality. You can disable it and try again to confirm. Maybe your change was deployed properly after the restart. I just noticed you have used `respond` mediator, which you can't use here. I will post another answer here. Try that.